# Why am I suddenly getting a SSL certificate chain validation error with Sonos Self-test Suite

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, sonos

Yesterday when I ran the Sonos self-test suite, everything was passing. But today when I run it I get 1 failure:

```
...
INFO Start Test Case: 41331557 ssl_validation test_certificate_chain
STOP 1011373133
STOP 41331557 ssl_validation test_certificate_chain
...
```

I've been debugging the test-suite (specifically `ssl_validation.py`), and it seems like there may be a problem with your Sonos SSL Validator endpoint.

Here's an extract of lines 456-458 of this file:

```
            url = "{0}/{1}/{2}".format(sonos_validator, leaf, chain)
            request = requests.post(url, data=file, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-sonos-cert-stream',
                                                             'Accept': 'application/x-sonos-cert-result'})
```

It seems like the test is making a `POST` request to `https://sslvalidator.sonos.com/v1/dcv/3be404741ff301e3030db77fc779608416d656b9/724cf533a5e58b6b9a148b69b8b3545e60e59b92`, and getting this as the `request.content`:

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Error</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
An error occurred while processing your request.<p>
Reference&#32;&#35;30&#46;374e7b5c&#46;1465987227&#46;da7cdcb
</BODY></HTML>
```

This seems to be an error with your endpoint. It leads to `status` (line 464) being `1011373133` which is incorrect (and also isn't listed in `dictionary_status_codes`) and causes the failure of this test.

Please can someone investigate if there is an issue with your validator. This issue is preventing us from submitting our new service to Sonos for approval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sonos test-suite has started passing again, and the endpoint `https://sslvalidator.sonos.com/v1/dcv/` seems to be returning the correct response again.